# Can I generate a random 32 bit key by using the Java hashCode and random English words?

Tags: hash, key-generation, entropy

I want to generate and communicate a 32 bit key to Bob over a phone conversation.  I know he happens to have the same Java and OS installed as I have.

Suppose I have a dictionary of 100,000 (English) words.  Can I uniformly at random pick two words, concatenate them and thus run `hashCode(word1 + word2)` *without loss of entropy* so that he can easily generate the same code?

As a follow-up question, can I then, if I want a 64 bit key simply pick four words and *concatenate the keys* `hashCode(word1 + word2)` with `hashCode(word3 + word4)` etc.?

*Edit: Ps: 100,000<sup>2</sup> > 2<sup>32</sup> if my math is right.*

Comment: It does seem like this would actually be easy to test, simply prep your dictionary and then set up a function to compute the hash of each combination and check the rest of the list for a collision. Perhaps akin to your thinking, 100000^2 is > 2^32 so it is not practical to expect the result to be collision-free (meaning, you have lost entropy).  The question is how much, right?  The collisions might be a lot more frequent than the ratio of bits in 100000^2 vs 2^32.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to accomplish? Why do you need the 32-bit key? For encryption? Other?

Comment: @NeilSmithline A key easily communicable over a phone conversation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short words:** it won't work well.

**In longer words:** Java's `String.hashCode()` method has biases; it works by repeatedly multiplying a running state by 31, then adding the numerical value of the next character. Letter usage in English is biased, groups of letters are biased, and these will show up. In other words, you lose some entropy.

Arguably, going through a list of words is a very weird thing to do. To choose a random word in a list of 100000 words, you must have a way to *uniformly* obtain a number in the 0 to 99999 range. Why, oh why, would you not use that value directly ? Why turn numbers into words, then hope that the `hashCode()` method will turn them back to numbers without losing too much entropy in the process, instead of just using the numbers directly ?

If you can generate a uniform integer in the 0..65535 range, then... that's it. You have a perfectly fine random 16-bit integer. Generate two of them, shift one of them by 16 bits, combine with bitwise OR (or with an addition), and you're done.

---

**Also**, a 32-bit key is atrociously weak, by nature, since it can have only 2<sup>32</sup> possible values, whose exhaustive enumeration is a piece of cake for a not-so-powerful PC. These beasts count time in gigahertz.

Comment: Yes, 32 is weak, but if I could concatenate keys, it would be no problem to have four words for a 64 bit key.  The purpose was an easily communicable key over a phone conversation.  And a four English words sentence is simpler to communicate than a 64 bit string of 1s and 0s.

Comment: English words are not completely appropriate for communicating keys over a phone because you cannot make sure that the guy at the other end will know how to write them properly. With a list of 100000 words, there will be some unusual ones... Would _you_ spell "poliorcetics" correctly on your first try ? For easy-to-dictate keys, I usually recommend lowercase hexadecimal: 16 possible characters, low confusion risk, 4 key bits per character. I have been personally involved in hex dictation in noisy environments, and it works well.